# ExecuteReaderAsync with ReadAsync and ObjectContext.Translate skips first row

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I have a code like this:

```
List<Models.MyModel> myobjects = new List<Models.MyModel>();
using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    if(await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        myobjects.AddRange(((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
        .ObjectContext
        .Translate<Models.MyModel>(reader,
            GetEntitySetName<DbModels.MyModel>(),
            MergeOption.NoTracking);
    }
}
```

However, this skips the first row in the resultset. If I change this to

```
List<Models.MyModel> myobjects = new List<Models.MyModel>();
using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    //if(await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        myobjects.AddRange(((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
        .ObjectContext
        .Translate<Models.MyModel>(reader,
            GetEntitySetName<DbModels.MyModel>(),
            MergeOption.NoTracking);
    }
}
```

I get back all the rows. Has anyone encountered this? If so, is there a workaround or a different way to call? The corresponding synchronous calls `cmd.ExecuteReader()` and `reader.Read()` run without any problems and always return all rows.

Comment: That's probably because the `Translate` method "takes ownership" of the reader and makes the first call to `Read` (or `ReadAsync`).  Are you just trying to understand the why, or is there a problem?

Comment: If Translate takes ownership of the reader, how are we supposed to perform asynchronous I/O if there's no corresponding TranslateAsync method?  This will absolutely hose throughput performance by tying up a thread while I/O is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `await reader.ReadAsync()` in your `if` condition you moved the reader to the next row. Then you passed the reader to the `Translate` method so it continues to read from it. Since you have already consumed some rows `Translate` is not able to read them anymore (i.e. it can't reset the reader to start reading from the first row)

Comment: Then where is the TranslateAsync method?  If it's doing the Read itself, we have no opportunity to perform asynchronous read operations.